# memory allocation errror cnn using keras and theano

Tags: deep-learning, theano, keras

I am running the cnn code released at [1] with some small data (6 train, 1 val, and 3 test instances).

[1] https://github.com/vsl9/Sentiment-Analysis-with-Convolutional-Networks

Here is the code with very slight modifications:

```
print "loading data..."
x = cPickle.load(open("imdb-train-val-test.pickle", "rb"))
revs, W, word_idx_map, vocab = x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]
# dimensions are as follows:
#   W.shape = (145, 300)
#   word_idx_map.len = 144
#   vocab.len = 144
print "data loaded!"

max_l = np.max(pd.DataFrame(revs)['num_words'])
datasets = make_idx_data(revs, word_idx_map, max_l=max_l, kernel_size=5)
```

**Put train data in separate NumPy arrays**

```
# Train data preparation
N = datasets[0].shape[0]
conv_input_width = W.shape[1]
conv_input_height = int(datasets[0].shape[1]-1)

# For each word write a word index (not vector) to X tensor
train_X = np.zeros((N, conv_input_height), dtype=np.int)
train_Y = np.zeros((N, 2), dtype=np.int)
for i in xrange(N):
    for j in xrange(conv_input_height):
    train_X[i, j] = datasets[0][i, j]
    train_Y[i, datasets[0][i, -1]] = 1

print 'train_X.shape = {}'.format(train_X.shape)
print 'train_Y.shape = {}'.format(train_Y.shape)
```

**Put validation data in separate NumPy arrays**

```
# Validation data preparation
Nv = datasets[1].shape[0]

# For each word write a word index (not vector) to X tensor
val_X = np.zeros((Nv, conv_input_height), dtype=np.int)
val_Y = np.zeros((Nv, 2), dtype=np.int)
for i in xrange(Nv):
    for j in xrange(conv_input_height):
    val_X[i, j] = datasets[1][i, j]
    val_Y[i, datasets[1][i, -1]] = 1

print 'val_X.shape = {}'.format(val_X.shape)
print 'val_Y.shape = {}'.format(val_Y.shape)
```

**Define and compile CNN model with Keras**

```
# Number of feature maps (outputs of convolutional layer)
N_fm = 300
# kernel size of convolutional layer
kernel_size = 5

model = Sequential()
# Embedding layer (lookup table of trainable word vectors)
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=W.shape[0], 
                output_dim=W.shape[1], 
                input_length=conv_input_height,
                weights=[W], 
                W_constraint=unitnorm()))
# Reshape word vectors from Embedding to tensor format suitable for Convolutional layer
model.add(Reshape((1, conv_input_height, conv_input_width)))

# first convolutional layer
model.add(Convolution2D(N_fm, 
                    kernel_size, 
                    conv_input_width, 
                    border_mode='valid', 
                    W_regularizer=l2(0.0001)))
# ReLU activation
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# aggregate data in every feature map to scalar using MAX operation
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(conv_input_height-kernel_size+1, 1)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.01))
# Inner Product layer (as in regular neural network, but without non-linear activation function)
model.add(Dense(2))
# SoftMax activation; actually, Dense+SoftMax works as Multinomial Logistic Regression
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# Custom optimizers could be used, though right now standard adadelta is employed
opt = Adadelta(lr=1.0, rho=0.95, epsilon=1e-6)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
          optimizer=opt,
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**Training the model for N_epoch epochs**

```
epoch = 0
val_acc = []
val_auc = []

N_epoch = 3

for i in xrange(N_epoch):
    model.fit(train_X, train_Y, batch_size=1, nb_epoch=1, verbose=1)
    output = model.predict_proba(val_X, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
    # find validation accuracy using the best threshold value t
    # ...
    epoch += 1

print '{} epochs passed'.format(epoch)
print 'Accuracy on validation dataset:'
print val_acc
print 'AUC on validation dataset:'
print val_auc
```

I'm getting the following error and I can't figure out what the issue is. Please consider that I check the dimensions of my input data and matrices are correct, I checked several times!

```
$ KERAS_BACKEND=theano python train_cnn_imdb.py

Using Theano backend.
loading data...
(145, 300)
data loaded!
train_X.shape = (6, 41)
train_Y.shape = (6, 2)
val_X.shape = (1, 41)
val_Y.shape = (1, 2)
Epoch 1/1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_cnn_imdb.py", line 155, in <module>
    model.fit(train_X, train_Y, batch_size=1, nb_epoch=1, verbose=1)
  File "/keras/models.py", line 640, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/keras/engine/training.py", line 1127, in fit
    callback_metrics=callback_metrics)
  File "/keras/engine/training.py", line 845, in _fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 811, in __call__
    return self.function(*inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 886, in __call__
    storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/link.py", line 325, in raise_with_op
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 873, in __call__
    self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
RuntimeError: BaseCorrMM: Failed to allocate output of 1 x 300 x -3 x -258
Apply node that caused the error: CorrMM{valid, (1, 1), (1, 1)}(InplaceDimShuffle{0,2,x,1}.0, Subtensor{::, ::, ::int64, ::int64}.0)
Toposort index: 43
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, (False, False, True, False)), TensorType(float32, 4D)]
Inputs shapes: [(1, 300, 1, 41), (300, 300, 5, 300)]
Inputs strides: [(1200, 4, 49200, 1200), (4, 1200, -108000000, -360000)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[InplaceDimShuffle{0,2,3,1}(CorrMM{valid, (1, 1), (1, 1)}.0)]]

Backtrace when the node is created(use Theano flag traceback.limit=N to make it longer):
  File "train_cnn_imdb.py", line 124, in <module>
    W_regularizer=l2(0.0001)))
  File "/keras/models.py", line 325, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/keras/engine/topology.py", line 514, in __call__
    self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/keras/engine/topology.py", line 572, in add_inbound_node
    Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/keras/engine/topology.py", line 149, in create_node
    output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors[0], mask=input_masks[0]))
  File "/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 464, in call
    filter_shape=self.W_shape)
  File "/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 1342, in conv2d
    filter_shape=filter_shape)

HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

Comment: also, I'm running on CPU and using the most recent versions of theano, keras, and numpy.

Comment: Shouldn't your Convolutional layer have a kernel of size:  kernel_size * kernel_size?

Comment: Hey did you find any solution for that?